# Pass parameters to action method requested on success of ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an ajax call like this

```
$.ajax({
   // code

   data:{
   //3 fields
   }

   success: function(data){
   $('#id').load('http://localhost:12345/cars/send')
   }

})

public ActionResult send(int a, string b, int c)
{
    var listOfCars =  //code to fetch list based on a,b,c
    return View(listOfCars);
}
```

The send action method in cars controller expects three parameters. It is not working the way I am doing and console window is showing error="Internal server error". If I add + data at the end of the load url then error="bad request".  Thanks in advance to help me work this out.

Comment: post all the code man

Comment: i hope your `http://localhost:12345/cars/send` doesn't have and html+body tag

Comment: @madalinivascu no it doesn't. Its a list view.

Comment: what is the code of your xhr request?,i think your problem is severside\

Comment: @madalinivascu This piece of code lies in an anonymous function called on windows.onload

Comment: lol man post the ajaxed asp

Comment: @madalinivascu do you mean send view/controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The send action method in cars controller expects three parameters*

You can simplify this more as this:

```js
var dataObj = { 
   // 3 fields 
};
$.ajax({
  // code
  data: dataObj,
  success: function(data) {
    $('#id').load('http://localhost:12345/cars/send', dataObj); //<-send the 3 fields here.
  }
})
```